# Why is my axios post request not working and sending null strings?

Tags: java, post, axios

made a simple chat component on a simple app to learn full stack but I'm not sure why my post request is not working when I use `axios` on react even though it works when I send a post request on postman. So, I think the issue is in my code. In postman, when I type in username and message in keys and give them string values, it works (see final console.log at the bottom). But when I do so using my code, it is sending null values instead of the string values I am passing. Even though I use `JSON.stringify` , somehow axios ends up sending `[object]` , is that the issue? If not, what am I doing wrong? Thank you very much. Here is my code:

```
updateChat = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { chat , username , chats } = this.state;

        this.setState({ chat : e.target.value });

        chats.push(chat);

        console.log("username: " + username + ", message: " + chat)

        var body = { 
            username : username,
            message : chat };

        console.log("body: " + body)

        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/api/chats/add', 
            data: body
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("Submitted: " + response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Post error: " + error);
        });
        this.pullChats();
    }

pullChats() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/chats')
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({ chats : res.data });
            console.log(res.data); 
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        });
    }

<div>
                {chats.map(chats =>
                <span className="badge badge-pill badge-warning p-3">
                    <p>{chats.message}</p> Username: <span className="text-green">{chats.username}</span>
                </span>)}
                <p>Posting as(username): <span className="text-green">{username}</span></p>
                <input type="text" value={chat} onChange={this.handleChatAddition}/>
                <button className="btn btn-light" onClick={this.updateChat}>Send</button>
            </div>
```

When I Console.log:

```
username: USERNAME, message: testest
```

2nd line:

```
body: {"username":"USERNAME","message":"testest"}
```

3rd line:

```
Submitted: [object Object]
```

4th line: (objects with id 1,2,6,7 and 8 were created from postman while the rest were created usig axios. For some reason, when I use axios, I am pushing in null values even though they are strings, I am not sure why)

```
(15) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, username: "UsernameABC", message: "This is my question"}
1: {id: 2, username: "User2", message: "Okokok"}
2: {id: 3, username: null, message: null}
3: {id: 4, username: null, message: null}
4: {id: 5, username: null, message: null}
5: {id: 6, username: "testesttesttrtr", message: "hitest"}
6: {id: 7, username: "testesttesttrtr", message: "hitest"}
7: {id: 8, username: "testesttesttrtr", message: "hitest"}
8: {id: 9, username: null, message: null}
9: {id: 10, username: null, message: null}
10: {id: 11, username: null, message: null}
11: {id: 12, username: null, message: null}
12: {id: 13, username: null, message: null}
13: {id: 14, username: null, message: null}
14: {id: 15, username: null, message: null}
length: 15
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Btw here is my backend:

Controller:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/")
public class ChatController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ChatRepository chatRepository;
    
    @GetMapping("chats")
    public List<Chat> getChats(){
        return this.chatRepository.findAll();
    }
    
    @PostMapping("chats/add")
    public Chat addChat( Chat newChat) {
        return chatRepository.save(newChat);
    }

}
```

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class Chat {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    
    @Column(name = "message")
    private String message;
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public Chat() {
        
    }
    
    public Chat(String username, String message) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.message = message;
    }



    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ChatRepository extends JpaRepository<Chat, Long> {

}
```

Application:

@

```
SpringBootApplication
public class ChatBackendApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ChatBackendApplication.class, args);
    }

    
    @Autowired
    private ChatRepository chatRepository;
    
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        this.chatRepository.save(new Chat("UsernameABC", "This is my question"));
        this.chatRepository.save(new Chat("User2", "Okokok"));
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the below method to do a post request using axios?

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/chats/add', { username: username, message: chat })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Similar to your get request

Comment: Yes I tried it also same result for some reason :/

Comment: Instead of using a dynamic variable try it with a simple string eg. username: "name1" and message: "message1". See if it's responding with expected results

Comment: yes it returns the same results even when I send strings in directly, they still get recorded as `null`